# Access annotated class member from main method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, static

In my Spring Boot application, I want to access my class's member variable (annotated as `@Value`, since it's a property being read from a properties file) from the `main` method. Since the static `main` method cannot read non-static variables, I made the variable static as well.

**Edit**: I also need to close the `ApplicationContext` returned by `SpringApplication.run()` based on the value of this property. I am updating the code below to reflect this.

My code looks something like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

// the variable I want to access in main
@Value("{property:}")
protected static String property;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(AccountApiApplication.class, args);

    if(new String("true").equals(property)) {
        SpringApplication.exit(context)
    }
}
```

**Edit**: There are two issues here:

1. `property` can't be static (as opposed to the code above), or the `@Value` annotation won't work with it. And I can't make it non-static, since then it won't be accessible from `main`.
2. I have been suggested a couple different approaches, which I'm considering for shutting down the ApplicationContext, but they might not work for me:

   - Using a `@PostConstruct` annotated `init()` method. Trouble is, I don't think the ConfigurableApplicationContext returned by `main()` can be accessed here.

   - Using `CommandLineRuuner.run()` or `ApplicationRunner.run()`. These `run()` methods seem to be executing before my Spring Batch job even starts, so I can't use these to shut down the ApplicationContext, or the application would be shut down even before my jobs execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot inject value expression in a static field (as well as for Spring components).

So the `@Value` field should be an instance field.  In order to be able to access to it, you should do that from an instance method as you guessed.

Note that to be able to manipulate the running `ApplicationContext` instance, the Spring context has to be completely initialized.

To achieve it, you should invoke the instance method that manipulates the `ApplicationContext` only after `SpringApplication.run()` is returned.
You should first retrieve the bean corresponding to the current application class by using the `BeanFactory.getBean()` method.
Then, you could invoke the instance method that needs the `ApplicationContext` :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    @Value("{property:}")
    protected String property;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(AccountApiApplication.class, args);
        AccountApiApplication app = context.getBean(AccountApiApplication.class);
        app.doMyTask(context);
    }

    public void doMyTask(ConfigurableApplicationContext context)  {
      if(property) {
          context.close();
      }
      else {
        // do something else
      }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would I call `init()` from `main()` without making it static? And if I make it static, I will need to make `property` static as well, which is seemingly a problem.

Comment: You are welcome. You don't call `init()`. Spring will make it for you. The `@PostConstruct` annotation is designed to perform any initialization after dependency injection.

Comment: I see. There's one more thing that I should have mentioned in the question, but I'll just ask it here. What I want to do in my if-else block is close the ApplicationContext returned by `SpringApplication.run()` in `main()` based on the value of the property. Will I be able to access the ApplicationContext in `init()`?

Comment: No you could not. You should use another way. I think that you should edit your question with this part. I will edit my answer according to.

Comment: Thanks! Seems to work quite well. Another small question, if you don't mind - is closing the ApplicationContext via context.close() the same as exiting the application through SpringApplication.exit(context)?

Comment: Fine !  I don't use both. So I prefer not tell a stupid thing. But javadoc and code of these are not really the same. So you should check them carefully if it matters for you.

Answer (score 1):

Injection into static variables doesn't work with Spring. There would be workarounds, but in your case they also wouldn't work. If you want to execute code after the startup of your application, create a new class which implements the `ApplicationRunner` interface (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-spring-application.html#boot-features-command-line-runner). That exists for exactly your usecase.

Comment: `ApplicationRunner.run()` and `CommandLineRunner.run()` seem to be executing the stuff inside `run()` before my Spring Batch job even starts.
What I want to do is close the ApplicationContext returned by `SpringApplication.run()` based on the value of the property. If I do that inside `run()`, the application will have closed even before my job executes.